# Best method to render a pdf on a view in android

Tags: android, pdf, android-droidtext

I know there are many library's available which are not suitable for commercial use like mupdf.My company is a startup and is not in a position to spend a lot .I am working on a magazine app.Can anyone suggest a good open-source library to use for rendering a single pdf or if that is not possible which one among the paid one's shall i prefer ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't seen any good free ones.  The 3 decent or better paid ones I've seen are Raede, Qoppa, and PdfTron.  That's pretty much worst to best order, and least expensive to most expensive.  Qoppa is what I've used, it hit the sweet spot of price and performance.

Comment: Thank you for the comment .Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webview with google docs.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<WebView
android:id="@+id/wv"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

```
 WebView wv= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
 wv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
 wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
 wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
 wv.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8ZDVNCvRWK8c3YzQVFaWjg1bEU/edit")//pdf uploaded to google docs. Some cases requires users to login and requires permission of the owner of the doc.
```

You can use intent. Your phone must have a pdf reader application.

```
  File file = new File("/sdcard/example.pdf");
            if (file.exists()) {
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } 
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(OpenPdf.this, 
                        "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

http://code.google.com/p/apv/source/checkout. APV PDF Viewer

http://code.google.com/p/apdfviewer/. APDF Viewer.

Comment: I want to embed the pdf reader in my application and i expect it to be quite fast when reading pdf's which are downloaded and kept in memory.So i dont think this is a good idea.